# react select doesn't select correct option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/pQB0vLY4X

```
const App = (item) => (
  <div>
    <select
      vlaue={item && item.space_size_uom}
      name="measure"
      className="input square_feet_select"
    >
      <option value="">
        Please select
      </option>
      <option value="sqft">
        sqft
      </option>
      <option value="sqm">
        sqm
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
);
```

item.space_size_uom is 'sqft', but why the item is not selected?

Answer (score 0):

you have two issues.. first is you have a typo in your select `vlaue` needs to be `value`

```
const App = ({space_size_uom) => (
  <div>
    <select
      value={space_size_uom || null}
      name="measure"
      className="input square_feet_select"
    >
```

second.. you dont have a change handler on the select. so when you try to select something you wont be able to. Now this isn't an issue if you want it to be a read-only dropdown. But you should probably just use something other than a select to show a unit of measurement.

If you want to be able to change / select something else you should use a state variable for this. Which would include changing this functional component to a react class.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { uom: props.space_size_uom};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          value={this.state.uom}
          name="measure"
          className="input square_feet_select"
          onChange={this.handleUomChange}
        >
         ....
     )
   }
}
```

and then your handler would look like

```
handleUomChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({uom: e.target.value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in `value` and `space_size_uom`. Also, you should deconstruct props like `const App = ({item}) => ..` to use `item` directly in your code;

Updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/ElXmYNZM4